# Bash for loop with no matching files gives error

Tags: regex, bash

I have a for loop for working with files in a directory that match a pattern:

```
for file in ${dir}/FileName_${TIMESTAMP}-*; do
```

This works if there is at least one file that matches, however when there isn't, it gives an error instead of skipping the loop (executing it zero times).

> dir/FileName_2014_11_28-*: No such file or directory

Why does it happen? How to prevent this?

Comment: for me, this just prints `dir/FileName_-*`. What is the body of your loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To evaluate a glob with no match to nothing, you need to turn `nullglob` on:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

Be careful, as it doesn't always do what you need. Try `ls nonexistent-prefix-*`: the output is identical to `ls` with no parameter. You might also be interested in the `failglob` option, which turns a non-matching glob into an error.

Comment: How can OP get `No such file or directory` with `nullglob` turned off?

Comment: @anubhava The loop isn't going to spit that out in any case. That's something inside the loop trying to use the unexpanded glob. (Either because it is quoted or because it fails to expand inside the loop as well.)

Comment: @anubhava Yes, the unexpanded glob was quoted inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array with `nullglob`.

```
shopt -s nullglob
arr=(${dir}/FileName_${TIMESTAMP}-*)
for file in "${arr[@]}"; do
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to accomplish this.

```
for file in $(find ${dir} -iname "FileName_${TIMESTAMP}-*")
do
    echo $file
done
```

Here in case if there is no files in the `${dir}` the for loop will not report any error and considers it an a empty list and moves to the next code block.